# Is it possible to use pattern matching on functions in python? Like, a function that will respond to multiple calls

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to make a class that acts like a list. However, I would like to be able to use all of the built-in list **repr**() functions and such, Is there any way to do something like this:

```py
class myList:
  ...
  def __getitem__(self, index):
    #custom getitem function
  def __setitem(self,index,value):
    #custom setitem function
  def toList(self):
    #returns a list

  #and a catch-all case:
  def __*__(*args):
    return self.toList().__*__(*args)
```

So, My question is, is it possible to make a catch-all case for something like that in python, to catch things like `__repr__, __str__, __iter__`, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I think, it should be `class myList(list):`. And where is the problem with overriding `__repr__(self)`?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible to trap such calls with a single method, in CPython at least.  While you can define special methods like `__getattr__`, even defining the low-level `__getattribute__` on a metaclass doesn’t work because the interpreter scans for special method names to build a fast lookup table of the sort used by types [defined in C](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html).  Anything that doesn’t actually possess such individual methods will not respond to the interpreter’s internal calls (*e.g.*, from `repr`).

What you can do is [dynamically generate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) (or augment, as below) a class that has whatever special methods you want.  The readability of the result might suffer too much to make this approach worthwhile:

```
def mkfwd(n):
  def fwd(self,*a): return getattr(self.toList(),n)(*a)
  return fwd
for m in "repr","str":
  m="__%s__"%m
  setattr(myList,m,mkfwd(m))
```